# buttons don't work after clicking the first one

Tags: python, discord.py

to further explain the title, i have a lfg system and i have a configuration embed with buttons that allows the vc owner to change it how they want it to. the first button, lock vc, works perfectly fine, but none of the other buttons work after that and there is no error or callback it justs says interaction failed. This only happens when i click the first button, if i click a different button first everything works up until i click the first button.

code snippet:

```py
class VCView(ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @ui.button(label="Lock", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def lock_vc(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        voice_channel = interaction.user.voice.channel
        canned = discord.Embed(description="Voice channel locked.",color=discord.Color.random())
        await voice_channel.set_permissions(interaction.guild.default_role, connect=False)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=canned)

    @ui.button(label="Unlock", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def unlock_vc(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        voice_channel = interaction.user.voice.channel
        chan = discord.Embed(description="Voice channel unlocked.",color=discord.Color.random())
        await voice_channel.set_permissions(interaction.guild.default_role, connect=True)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=chan)

    @ui.button(label="Rename", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def rename_vc(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(RenameModal())
```

also for my kick config what else would be better to use than a button since the button will have a member parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You should make buttons by making a class for each button so you can use the built-in callback. This lets them be pressed as long as the interaction is active. I used something similar in a project recently.

```
@bot.tree.command(name="register", description="Registration command")
async def register(interaction: discord.Interaction):
   
    await interaction.response.defer()
    view = RegistrationView(interaction) #make a class for the view
    message = await interaction.followup.send("Registration (Continued)", view=view) 
    #send the view
```

Here is the class for my view:

```
class RegistrationView(View):
    def __init__(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        super().__init__()
        #have to add buttons, when you use your decorator method they do that automatically
        self.add_item(SubmitRegistrationButton(self))
        self.add_item(CancelRegistrationButton(self))

        self.interaction = interaction
```

Buttons with callbacks:

```
class SubmitRegistrationButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self, registration_view):
        super().__init__(label="Submit Registration", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="registrationsubmitbutton")
        self.registration_view = registration_view

#you used callbacks with the decorators, here is the second way to make a callback
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction): 
        await self.registration_view.submit_registration_button(interaction)


class CancelRegistrationButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self, registration_view):
        super().__init__(label="Cancel", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id="registrationcancelbutton", row=2)
        self.registration_view = registration_view

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("User Cancelled")
        self.registration_view.stop() 
#ends the interaction. until then you can press the buttons as much as you want
```